# Representing an immutable hierarchy using tuples

Tags: python, hierarchy, tuples

I am trying to represent a hierarchy using `namedtuple`. Essentially, every node has three attributes relevant to the hierarchy: `parent`, `leftChild` and `rightChild` (they also have some attributes that carry the actual information, but that is not important for the question). The problem is the circular reference between parents and children. Since I need to specify all values at construction time, I run into problems because parents need the children to be constructed first, and children need the parents to be constructed first. Is there any way around this (other than using a custom class instead of tuples)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Remove parent field. You can still implement any tree-manipulation operations efficient without keeping reference to parent node.

Comment: "Manipulation" doesn't exist for immutable types.

Comment: The whole point of this is to have convenient access to the hierarchy, so removing the parent field would defeat the original purpose.

Comment: @Ignacio: Is functional programming just a myth?

Answer (score 0):

One trick is not to use an object reference, but instead, a symbolic ID that you maintain in a hash table.